# Dispose an image object

Tags: javascript, image

When creating a new Image element in javascript, Google Chrome's memory tool (Developer tools > Timeline > Memory) considers it as a new DOM element, naturally.

In my case, I'm ending up with 1500+ DOM elements, and I wish to get rid of them. I have tried to save all objects in an array and delete all of them in a loop when I'm ready creating all objects, resulting in the following error:

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'removeChild' of null`

That indicates the Image objects doesn't appear in the actual DOM.

```
var images = [];
var i, image;

for( i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) {
    image = new Image();
    image.src = urls[i];
}

// other stuff happens

for( i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) {
    // apparently this doesn't work because I'm not adding the image to my DOM
    // images[i].parentNode.removeChild( images[i] );

    // delete images
}
```

**Is there a way to remove/delete/unset/dispose the Image objects?**

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Setting `images = null` would remove your reference in code to the object. However, to implement its `load` event, Chrome has to have its own internal reference to the object.

That is, you could have code like this:

```
for( i = 0; i < urls.length; i++ ) { 
    image = new Image(); 
    image.src = urls[i]; 
    image.onload = function(){alert('Test');};
    image = null;
}
```

This way you would still get a lot of "Test" alerts, even though you do not have a reference to these objects.

Hence, my *guess* is that it is a bug in Chrome, not in your code.

Update: looking through the Chromium source sort of proves that (I mean the comment on lines 67-71 of this file, especially the FIXME note http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/WebCore/bindings/v8/custom/V8HTMLImageElementConstructor.cpp ):

> ```
> // Make sure the document is added to the DOM Node map. Otherwise, the HTMLImageElement instance
> // may end up being the only node in the map and get garbage-ccollected prematurely.
> // FIXME: The correct way to do this would be to make HTMLImageElement derive from
> // ActiveDOMObject and use its interface to keep its wrapper alive. Then we would
> // remove this code and the special case in isObservableThroughDOM.
> ```

Comment: thanks! I know your answer was last, but you have actually done some research

Comment: Has this been fixed since or is this still a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug! You added a listener, but did not remove it. By doing "image = null" you're only removing this concrete reference. Object still exists in a memory, although no reference to it is left. To let GS free it, you have to remove the event by "image.onload=null"

Comment: @shal is absolutely right. Not a bug! You just need to clean up after yourself fully to allow the garbage collector to do its job. !Sometimes easier said than done!)

Comment: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLImageElement'.]

Answer (score 7):

If you are not adding them to the DOM (like using `appendChild` to a parent), then `removeChild` is useless. The Image objects are only in the memory.

And to dispose items in the memory, you only need to remove references to these objects (like set the referencing variable to null), and garbage collection will do the rest. If you can't null them all, they won't be GC'ed.

Comment: Just curious, if you null the object will that technically still remove the memory allocated from the `image` after being GC'd?

Answer (score 4):

To get rid of the bug described by "naivists" of chrome and specilly IE and EDGE.
You can change the image source to empty so it take zero memory.

```
image.src = '';
image = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, assigning `null` should clean it up: `images[i] = null`

Answer (score 1):

I think only way is to do this:

```
for( i = 0; i < images.length; i++ ) 
  images[i] = null;
}

// or just 
images = null;
```

Comment: Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'HTMLImageElement'.